# Does having a single-partition collection (fixed) affect the global replication?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

We have a single-partition (fixed) CosmosDB collection. Our global replication setting is Write: East US, Read: East US, West US. We are observing much higher latencies (for reads) when accessing the collection from a West US datacenter (with West US set as the 1st preferred location), than accessing the collection from East US. Does the fact that this is a single-partition collection mean that we can't take advantage of global replication properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can use fixed collections with global replication. Please use the preferred region setting to read from the local/closest region. By default, the SDK would read from the write/primary region, so you must override it.

Something like the following:

```
ConnectionPolicy connectionPolicy = new ConnectionPolicy();

// Setting read region selection preference
connectionPolicy.PreferredLocations.Add(LocationNames.WestUS); // first preference
connectionPolicy.PreferredLocations.Add(LocationNames.EastUS); // second preference

DocumentClient docClient = new DocumentClient(
    accountEndPoint,
    accountKey,
    connectionPolicy);
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-global-distribution-documentdb#connecting-to-a-preferred-region-using-the-documentdb-api

Comment: We have set the preferred region setting to read from the local region for all of our regions, but the reads in the non-primary/write region have unusually high latency. Since we don't see this kind of problem with partitioned collections we just wanted to rule out fixed collections being the problem.

Comment: Got it. If you need support, please email AskCosmosDB@microsoft.com